# Get highlighted text - and navigate to URL

Tags: jquery

is it possible to throw the jquery-select() event on a text which is inside a div element?
here is my example but it doesnt work.

```
<div id='id1'>Hello text</div>
$("#id1").select( function () { 
  alert("something was selected");
});
```

My goal is to select a word in a text and to put this selected word in an URL and to open a new window with this url.
For example i mark or rather i select the word hello, the word hello should apear in this url

```
window.open('http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=Hello');
```

i am not sure if the select-event is the right way.
please help.
sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Translate a selected (highlighted) text portion

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/momado/1/edit?html,js,console,output)***

```js
function getSelRange() {
  var notIE8 = window.getSelection;
  var rng = notIE8 ? window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
  return $.trim(rng);
}

$('#id1').mouseup(function() {
  var selRange = getSelRange(); // THE HIGHLIGHTED TEXT PORTION
  if(selRange) window.open('https://translate.google.com/#en/de/'+ selRange); // TRANSLATE
});
```

```html
<div id='id1'>
  Please highlight a text range you want to translate.
  Translating text is really cool. You should try it!
</div>
```

<sup>**NB**: `notIE8` means lower than or equal to IE8 ;)</sup>

P.S: If you don't use jQuery and you need to support older browsers, than make sure to use `onclick` function and [a Polyfill for `.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Polyfill);
otherwise use JS's [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) as usual.

Answer (score 2):

No, jQuery.select() is limited to text input fields and textareas.

javascript has some varied options:

```
if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
} else if (document.getSelection) {
    txt = document.getSelection();
} else if (document.selection) {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
} else return;
alert(txt);
```

But you would have to bind that to some kind of listener event. Most applications use a right click menu or something.